# Centos 7 - ssh-keygen is not generating keys

Tags: centos, rhel

`sshd` service doesn't start due to missing keys. When I try to generate the keys using

```
ssh-keygen -t dsa
```

I just get message saying:

```
Generating public/private dsa key pair.
```

I don't get prompt to specify the location of key files. It just doesn't do anything.

And when I use

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

I get

```
Generating public/private rsa key pair. rsa_generate_private_key : Key generation failed.
```

I tried running it using different iSO and by using RHEL 7. Always I have this problem. I tried commands with `-v` option but log output is not obtained yet.

Comment: "Key generating failed" or "Key generation failed" ? When quoting system messages it's important to copy-paste them exactly

Comment: Are you running your Centos in a virtualized machine? Are you root? The problem happens the same using a newly created test user?

Comment: Thanks leonbloy. I have corrected the error message. I am running in virtualbox. This is happening with root and newly created user also

Comment: If you're just seeing it exiting without printing out a description of why, if leonboy's suggestion doesn't fix the issue, it might be useful to do `strace -fvvo output.txt ssh-keygen -t dsa` to see if the `output.txt` file gives you an indication of what's happening. But yeah I second the notion that it's good form to copy text exactly, starting with the prompt you type a command into and ending with the prompt that gets generated after the command exits. That way if it's truly not printing anything useful we'll know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Thanks leonbloy and Bratchley]

Using strace I compared with working fedora output with centos. Both looked nearly same. (fixed few issues with networking thinking this might be the reason).

Looked at source code

`http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-74/openssh/key.c.orig?txt`

which just calls openssl libraray. So, directly tried generating the rsa certificates using openssl.

This gave me error which pointed to

`https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1150286'

Adding environment variable

`export OPENSSL_ia32cap=~0x4000000000000000`

Fixed the issue.

Comment: I just had to revisit this thread due to the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Could be some entropy issue with the virtualized guest , but it's strange that you don't get any error messages (add -vvv to increase verbosity, look into the logs).

See also what `cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail` gives you.

You could also try to run `rngd -r /dev/urandom` before generating the keys

(if you don't have `rngd` you can install it with `yum install rng-tools`)

Comment: Before `rngd -r /dev/urandom` it is 800 odd where as after `rngd -r /dev/urandom` its giving 3k but still same issue.